# Как в задании 21 ЕГЭ группируются в одно правило обособленные определения?

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис, егэ

Можно ли считать определения "...дерзкие и беспокойные, они шмыгают по веткам..."
и "...желна, недоверчивая и пугливая,..." относящимися к одному правилу?

Comment: А не хотите всё задание привести?

Comment: Если вам дан (или будет дан) исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 1):

1) ...**дерзкие и беспокойные, они шмыгают по веткам..**

2) .**..желна, недоверчивая и пугливая,**

Это разные правила. В первом случае обособленное определение относится **к местоимению** и поэтому обособляется в любой позиции.

Во втором случае обособляется определение, стоящее **после** определяемого существительного.

Розенталь, см.правило 1 и 10.

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=109#pp109

Answer (score 1):

Да, это одно правило - ***обособление двух или более одиночных согласованных  определений***. Знаки препинания поставлены в соответствии с этим правилом.

Добавлю ответ **иллюстрацией задания** 21 ЕГЭ, чтобы всё стало ясно:

Найдите предложения, в которых ***запятая ставится в соответствии с одним и тем же правилом пунктуации***. Запишите номера этих предложений.

(1)В густых прибрежных лесах Уссурийского края водится бесчисленное множество редких птиц. (2)Вот рыжие красавицы сойки с голубой полоской на крыльях и белой на хвосте. (3)И характер у них как у капризных барышень: ***дерзкие и беспокойные, они шмыгают по веткам с резкими криками невдалеке от человека.*** (4)Однако близко к себе не подпускают: прячутся в листве, а то и вовсе скрываются в глубь зарослей. (5)Барабанный бой в этом лесу совсем не означает, что рядом военный лагерь.(6) Так трудится удивительная птица здешних мест — желна, ***недоверчивая и пугливая.***(7) Она издаёт резкие крики и, как все дятлы, прячется за деревьями. (8)А вот, распластав огромные крылья, с дерева слетела круглая тёмная птица. (9)Это хищный уссурийский филин — царь ночи.